# Passing object as post - reset of LocalDateTime

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, post, localdatetime

i pass an object ObjectDTO as POST that have some org.joda.time.LocalDateTime parameter.

```
public class ObjectDTO dto {
  ...

  private LocalDateTime dataesecuzione;
    
  private LocalDateTime oraesecuzione;

  public LocalDateTime getDataesecuzione() {
        return dataesecuzione;
  }

  public void setDataesecuzione(LocalDateTime dataesecuzione) {
        this.dataesecuzione = dataesecuzione;
  }

  public LocalDateTime getOraesecuzione() {
        return oraesecuzione; 
  }
    
  public void setOraesecuzione(LocalDateTime oraesecuzione) {
        this.oraesecuzione = oraesecuzione;
  }
  ...

}

@PutMapping("/api/get/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Integer> update(@PathVariable("id") int id, @RequestBody ObjectDTO dto) {
...
}
```

The problem is that all the LocalDateTime parameter are reset to current date/time.

How can I solve the problem?

Thanks

Comment: have you registered JodaModule in the object mapper?

Comment: hi, I dont'use JodaModule. At what point of the code I've to register? Where id the object mapper?

Answer (score 0):

To let Jackson deserialize the Joda Date Time, register JodaModule in the object mapper bean

```
@Bean
  ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
    return objectMapper;
  }
```